# Place image and Text in same title line

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

I have title part in latex code and i want to put image in left side. Page is in center.

```
\title{\vspace{-15mm}
\fontsize{25pt}{10pt}\selectfont
\textbf{\hspace*{-1pt} 
\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{./img/logo.png}\hfill 
\hspace*{-100pt} This Text}}
```

But After this code "This Text" is going to left side (something between left and center)
How to put them correctly?
Thanks for attention...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, corected now. One of `\hfill`'s on both sides can be removed, but now it is easier to understand, how the centering is obtained: one hidden plus one explicit, corrected by two on the right hand side.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\title{\vspace{-15mm}
\fontsize{25pt}{10pt}\selectfont
\textbf{%\hspace*{-1pt} 
%\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{./img/logo.png}\hfill 
\makebox[0pt][l]{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{it}}
\hfill
This Text \hfill\hfill
%\hspace*{-100pt} This Text}}
}}

\maketitle

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but its not answer to my question. I want this image to be in the left side and text to be in center. By default all of them are in center. Also this text is going down, but it mustn't depend on picture. I think in must use 2 columns for that but i don't know how.

Comment: @EminMastizada  Oh, my mistake! Corrected to center the text.

Comment: thanks, it solves problem, but, if i could solve the problem with alignment it would be great. (Text position is going under of image because image is bigger than text size). Now I'm using 2 extra line of text for solving this :)

Comment: @EminMastizada And where should be the text? Aligned to the top of the picture?

Answer (score 4):

Yet another answer using the `tcolorbox` package.

My answer constructs a sidebyside box named `imagetextbox` which will take the image to its lefthand (upper) side und the text to the righthand (lower) side.

The macro `\imagetext` takes one image and the text as arguments. All dimensions could be adapated if needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{imagetextbox}[3][]{%
  before=\par\bigskip\noindent,after=\par\medskip,
  blank,sidebyside,center lower,
  fontlower=\fontsize{25pt}{28pt}\selectfont\bfseries,
  width=\textwidth-#2-#3,
  lefthand width=#2,
  sidebyside gap=#3,#1}

\newcommand{\imagetext}[3][0.15]{%
\begin{imagetextbox}[]{#1\textwidth}{3mm}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#2}%
  \tcblower%
   #3%
\end{imagetextbox}}

\begin{document}
\imagetext{example-image-a}{This Text}
\lipsum[1]

\imagetext{example-image-b}{This title\\has two lines}
\lipsum[2]

\imagetext{example-image-c}{This title\\has\\three lines}
\lipsum[3]

\imagetext[0.25]{example-image-a}{Larger image}
\lipsum[4]

\imagetext[0.35]{example-image-a}{Even larger image}
\lipsum[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If the title is only on one line, then this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\author{A. U. Thor}
\title{%
  \fontsize{25}{32}\bfseries % boldface 25pt
  \makebox[\textwidth][s]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{\includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{duck}}%
    \hfill
    This text%
    \hfill
  }%
}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The trick is to make the image take no space. I use a `\textwidth` wide box, where the contents is centered and no padding is added at the left and the right: `\makebox[\textwidth][s]{...}`. Inside it the image is set in

```
\makebox[0pt][l]{...}
```

so TeX will assume the box takes no width.

[image]

With a title on two lines, a `tabular` is probably the easiest way out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\author{A. U. Thor}
\title{%
  \fontsize{25}{32}\bfseries % boldface 25pt
  \makebox[\textwidth][s]{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \includegraphics[width=0.15\textwidth]{duck}}%
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
    This title\\
    has two lines
    \end{tabular}%
    \hfill
  }%
}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works good too, but problem with page alignment stays. (because of image size this text is going very down)

Comment: ooh a duck! `:)`