# linespace in tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

How to change the line spacing of the text inside `\imagetext` command shown in the link

[Place image and Text in same title line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146781/place-image-and-text-in-same-title-line)

Comment: Could you explain a little more what you want ? Maybe show an image of what you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want to use `\imagetext` command from [Thomas F. Sturm answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146836/1952).

As you can see, all examples uses manual breaks `\\` for line breaking in text beside the image.

If I'm not wrong, `\\` always accept an optional parameter which increases the default space between lines. So, `\\[1cm]` will add an additional 1cm beteween lines, while `\\[-1cm]` will make this space 1cm shorter.

Next code taken from the linked answer shows some examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{imagetextbox}[3][]{%
  before=\par\bigskip\noindent,after=\par\medskip,
  blank,sidebyside,center lower,
  fontlower=\fontsize{25pt}{28pt}\selectfont\bfseries,
  width=\textwidth-#2-#3,
  lefthand width=#2,
  sidebyside gap=#3,#1}

\newcommand{\imagetext}[3][0.15]{%
\begin{imagetextbox}[]{#1\textwidth}{3mm}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{#2}%
  \tcblower%
   #3%
\end{imagetextbox}}

\begin{document}
\imagetext{example-image-a}{This Text\\ has two lines}
\lipsum[1]

\imagetext{example-image-b}{This title\\[1cm]has two lines}
\lipsum[2]

\imagetext{example-image-c}{This title\\[-2cm]has two lines}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]